# Click on something that's not a sprite

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm tryng to handle a click event that does not clicked on a sprite.

My first aproach would be handling normal JS events:

```
class EditorListener {

   constructor(editor) {
       ...
       if(window) {
           window.addEventListener('click', this.onWindowClick.bind(this));
       }
   }

   onWindowClick(event) {
       if(event.target && event.target.tagName == 'CANVAS') {
           Events.fire(EventType.CLICK_NOWHERE);
       }
   }
}
...
```

The problem is that this is called when I click sprites.

The goal is to simply close a dialog when I click nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tap anywhere and run the function:

```
game.input.onTap.add(onTap, this);

function onTap(pointer) 
{
}
```

Tap on these objects and run the function onDown

```
// enable input for some objects
yourObject1.inputEnabled = true;
yourObject2.inputEnabled = true;

yourObject1.events.onInputDown.add(onDown, this);
yourObject2.events.onInputDown.add(onDown, this);

function onDown(object, pointer) 
{
    // on down function
}
```

Comment: the tap does not contain the sprite that was clicked therefore i cannot know when i clicked not in a sprite =(

Comment: I don't really understand you, it's almost impossible to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to detect a click that is not on a sprite... idk how to sound simpler then that sorry

Comment: Try to add this code after "game input"   yourSprite.input.enabled = false; Does this make any changes?

Comment: no dude, ur not getting it. I want a click event, but i want to add a check to that click event that i clicked a sprite, in a way i can run code when i DO CLICK on something, that is not a sprite. Got it ?

Comment: Then I would add one click/touch event to all objects except "sprites", and if needed I would add another click/touch event to "sprites", so I can run two different functions, but I hope you will find a solution.

Comment: thats the thing. `Then I would add one click/touch event to all objects except "sprites"`. Thats what i want. How to do that , even with backgrounds/no objects ?